# How to join and get most recent date with all other columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let say, we have five table A,B,C,D,E and all contain one of column as upd_date. I want to join all columns of these 5 table(Number is primary key) where upd_date column will contain the latest date among 5 tables. My tables are like:

**Table A**

```
[Number, Date1, Cost]
[12345, '2019-07-26 04:11:43.000', 2342]
```

**Table B**

```
[Number, Date1, expense]
[12345, '2021-01-26 04:11:43.000', 23442]
```

**Table C**

```
[Number, Date1, equipment]
[12345, '2019-02-02 04:11:43.000', 'tents']
```

**Table D**

```
[Number, Date1, delivery]
[12345, '2020-02-26 04:11:43.000', 'completed']
```

**Table E**

```
[Number, Date1, mode]
[12345, '2018-07-26 04:11:43.000', 2342]
```

I want to return like:

**Result table**

[Number, expense, equipment, delivery, mode, cost, Most_recent_date]
[12345, 23442, 'tents', 'completed', 'courier', 2342 , '2021-01-26 04:11:43.000']

Comment: Is that the most recent data across all tables? Sample data and expected results would help. Thanks

Comment: Post sample data and expected output.

Comment: updated with sample example

Answer (score 0):

Use `union all` and `top`.  Perhaps the most efficient method is:

```
select top (5) x.*
from ((select top (5) a.*
       from a
       order by upd_date desc
      ) union all
      (select top (5) b.*
       from b
       order by upd_date desc
      ) union all
      (select top (5) c.*
       from c
       order by upd_date desc
      ) union all
      (select top (5) d.*
       from d
       order by upd_date desc
      ) union all
      (select top (5) e.*
       from e
       order by upd_date desc
      )
     ) x
order by upd_date desc;
```

This chooses the 5 most recent rows from each table, combines them, and then chooses the 5 from the combined set.

Note:  This uses `*` to select all columns, assuming that the tables have compatible columns (same number with compatible types).  You may need to list the columns you want explicitly.